# Cannot invoke Java applet methods from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I am trying to load an applet in a browser and invoke it's methods from JavaScript. The applet is called as follows:

```
var attributes = {
    id: 'applet1',
    name: 'applet1',
    code: 'com.applet.MyApplet.class',
    archive: '../applet.jar',
    width: 0, height: 0,
    mayscript: 'yes',
    scriptable: 'true',
    separate_jvm: 'true'};
var parameters = {tokenType: "'" + jQuery("#tokenType").text() + "'"};
var version = '1.6';
var appletTag = deployJava.getAppletTag(attributes, parameters, version);
jQuery('body').append(appletTag);
```

and I can see the tag when I reference the above in the console using "document.applet1".

But when I try to invoke a simple public method I have exposed in the MyApplet class, I get the following:

```
TypeError: "document.applet1.isActive()" is not a function
```

The init() method never seems to be called either. I see all of the security prompts but go ahead and allow the applet to be loaded.
I am using Firefox 35.0.1 with the Java Applet Plugin version 7 update 45.

**Edit:**

The following is the JS code that first tries to access the applet:

```
function issueNewToken(wrongPasswordMessage) {
  console.log('issueNewToken() called at ' + new Date().getTime());
  try {
       if (!document.applet1.isActive()) { // ERROR OCCURS HERE!
           setTimeout(function () {
               issueNewToken(wrongPasswordMessage);
           }, 1000);
           console.log('applet not ready yet. call rescheduled at ' + new Date().getTime());
           return;
       }
       // the applet is not ready to call yet
   } catch (err) {
       console.error(err);
       if (err instanceof TypeError) {
           setTimeout(function () {
               issueNewToken(wrongPasswordMessage);
           }, 1000);
           console.log('applet not ready yet (exception caught). call rescheduled at ' + new Date().getTime());
           return;
       }
       // all other errors such as user do not allow applet to run
       else {
           hideModalCover();
           alert(err.message);
           return;
       }
   }

    /// We have access to applet.. more work done here...
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that you enable Java Console and examine the logs (On Windows: Control Panel => Java => Advanced Tab => Java Console Option => Show console).

Also post the code you wrote to call the applet method, it may help.

Comment: @ivan.aguirre Yes, I have the console open but it is not logging anything of interest. I'll update the question with the code I use to call the Applet.

Comment: Check the applet manifest. Take a look at 
[caller_allowable parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#caller_allowable).

Comment: @ivan.aguirre parameter is set as follows: "Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *"